# Vue Router Keep-Alive Include not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I've a Vue Router like this:

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Inbox',
      component: Inbox
    }]
})
```

In the main app.vue I've:

```
  <div id="app">
    <main>
      <keep-alive include="Inbox">
        <router-view></router-view>
      </keep-alive>
    </main>
  </div>
```

It won't work, but if I remove the include it works (in all routes).
What is missing here for the keep-alive only work in the Inbox component?

Comment: Do you have a `name` in your `Inbox` component?

Comment: That was it. Thank you, so much. If you want to create an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your route is named but your component is not, therefore `keep-alive include="Inbox"` is not applying to any components.

The fix is to add `name: 'Inbox'` to your component definition for `Inbox`

Comment: This won't work for child components under `Inbox`, would it? I get an error when trying something similar, but I have a child component.